# How to invoke struts1 action from a timer?

Tags: java, timer, struts-1

I got a struts1 web application, mainly forms submitted to the struts Actions on the server side. I would need to add a timer, that once in a while will read the parameters for the same form but from other source (like DB or file). So, basically the form will be filled in the timer, instead of the page. the questions is: how do I invoke the same Action for the Form? but from the timer thread, and not through the web page.

Comment: The same way you would for any Ajax request; get the form values, post it to the action, and do something with the response.

Comment: @DaveNewton The "post it to the action" is exactly the part that I am asking about. I know I am probably missing something very simple, but I do not know what. So, assuming I am in my "timer code", I have all the values, and created the Form object with assigned attributes. Now what? How do I actually invoke the "Action" class from the Timer class? just create new instance and call it? but how about all the filters/interceptors/transactions that are bound to the action execution? Thank you!

Comment: ... The timer will exist on the *client* side; there's no such thing as creating an instance of an action on the browser. You make an Ajax request; doing this is trivially searchable on SO and the web in general. Ajax requests, by default, go through the exact same process on the server side as non-Ajax requests.

Comment: I mean, as much as I'd like the "bounty", there's nothing particularly unusual about this, and it's documented all over the place.

Comment: @DaveNewton I will try to explain better. The TIMER I am referring to, is a planned entity to run on the server side. The server will once a day schedule a process, that will read from an external database some parameters, that are similar to what is submitted from the web. So, the process will build on the server side, the same form that would be submitted from the web, except that the "client" in this case is the internal timer on the server. From that point, I would like to submit that form to the action, to make the exact process to work, as if the process submitted from the web.

Comment: To rephrase: entirely on the server side you want to make an HTTP request with a form submit? Why? Why not just call the business logic directly? In any case, you *can* make an HTTP request from the server side using any random HTTP library, and it will be processed like any other HTTP request.

Comment: @DaveNewton this is to maintain the same transaction rules and any other objects injected to the action during the process and pre validation. this is why I was seeking to invoke the action as if it was called by real submitted form. Calling an HTTP SUBMIT is not an option. I know this is not a standard solution, a it even might be not the best or not right solution, but this is "my" reality and this is what I need to implement. Thank you!

Comment: It makes no sense that making an HTTP request isn't an option. It is *the* option if you want to perfectly replicate a client-side form submit from the server side. Otherwise you'll need to do what you'd expect: extract all the logic from the web app and make it a dependent library that you can call from the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript timer objects to create these time based events as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers). And then use normal ajax/event based form submission for [example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery).